# Choosing a wine that complements a meal

Tags: drinks, pairing

I've heard that particular types of wine are good matches for particular types of food. I'm fairly new to wine being served with a meal I prepared, and I'd like to learn about **how** and **why** I should pick a wine that complements the rest of the meal.

I made this community wiki because I didn't name a *particular* meal to match. I'd like to spend some time learning about this topic in general.

Comment: Voted to close just due to the sheer scope of such a question. Community wiki or not it isn't really a fit for here.

Comment: Agreed, question needs to be more specific.

Comment: Yet it has been adequately answered, touche.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's a ridiculously huge question. So huge that you'd need a whole book to answer it! Fortunately, that book has been written:

[image: What to Drink With What You Eat]

[**What to Drink With What You Eat**

The Definitive Guide to Pairing Food with Wine, Beer, Spirits, Coffee, Tea —  Even Water — Based on Expert Advice from America's Best Sommeliers.

by Andrew Dornenburg and Karen Page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821257188)

If you really want to understand this issue, this is by far the best answer. Worth every penny.